# Infinitive of purpose or "for verb-ing"

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, participles, verbing

> The chambers inside the pyramid were closed **(to/for)** visitors **(to clean and repair/for cleaning and repairing)**.

Which is the correct alternative in both the brackets, and why?
Please explain in detail the correct usage and grammar.

The essence required is:

> The chambers were closed so that no more visitors would come inside them and because the chambers needed maintenance.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Which is the correct alternative in both the brackets, and why?

Comment: If the chambers are _closed to visitors for cleaning and repairing_ (or, more idiomatically, _for maintenance and repair_), the meaning is what you are after here. If they are _closed for visitors to clean and repair_, they are closed so that visitors may come and clean/repair them, which doesn't really make much sense from a tourism point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence includes two prepositional (or phrasal) verbs that have specific meaning.

> *Close to* means to block access by a category of people or things that follow the preposition.
>
> *Close for* means block access to accomplish a particular purpose.

Your sentence contains both, even though the word *close* is not repeated.

> The chambers inside the pyramid were closed *to* visitors *for* cleaning and repair.

Answer (score -1):

The correct sentence is:

> The chambers inside the pyramid were closed to visitors for cleaning and repair.

Although *maintenance* would probably be better than *repair*.

Here *to* is used to indicate the parties affected by the closure of the chambers. *For* is used in the sense of *for the purpose of*.

Comment: but the purpose, if explicitly there, is written in the form of "to  verb" or infinitive of purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say there

Comment: The goal of any action is preferred to be written in the infinitive form of verb. I guess.

Comment: Well, as a native speaker I've never learned about infinitives and so on. But I can guarantee the sentence above is correct. No doubt someone more scholarly will come along and give you the technicalities.

Comment: Yeah but i needed logical reasons for why one is correct and why one is not. Anyways thanks for your input.

Comment: also repairing is parallel with cleaning, as both are gerunds. Why use repair, a noun, with a gerund?

Comment: As another native speaker, I agree with Elendil that the 'mixed' usage sounds right. Maybe the reason is that the noun _repair_ is the preferred form, but since there isn't a basic noun form of _clean_, the gerund _cleaning_ is used.

Comment: @tushain The word "cleaning" isn't a gerund in this case-- a gerund would be modified by an adverb, whereas "cleaning" would be modified by an adjective in this case: "closed for scrupulous cleaning"/"*closed for scrupulously cleaning".

Comment: @NeilCoffey 
Gerunds act as nouns. They are modified by both adjectives and adverbs. But gerunds never act as adjectives.
The chambers inside the pyramid were closed to visitors for (their )cleaning and repairing. It's the case of possessive form + gerunds.
Source - Grammar Girl
http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/what-is-a-gerund

Comment: @tushain repairing is incorrect in this case. Google 'closed for repairing' and see how many accurate hits you get compared to 'closed for repair'.

Comment: @tushain Where do you get the notion that the goal of an action is “preferred to be written in [the] infinitive form of [a] verb”? A goal is not a single thing; there are different ways to express it. One way, the one that fits here, is with the preposition _for_, which requires verbal objects to be gerunds in contemporary English. _To_ can also express goals in some constructions (and requires verbal objects to be infinitives), but not here.

Comment: @tushain You're taking an informal definition of "gerund" which is sometimes adopted, but doesn't help us here. It is possible for an "ing" form to take on a combination of verbal and nominal features but where the *verbal* features essentially win out in various respects. That is what I and many linguistics would strictly refer to by "gerund" and is essentially the usage that would lead one to expect "repairing" rather than "repair" here...

Comment: ...It doesn't matter terribly much what you call it, but the point is that "cleaning" in this case ostensibly on the "noun-like" end of scale, whereas it would need to be more towards the "verb-like" end to be conjoined with "repairing" rather than "repair".

Answer (score -1):

In various cases where you evoke the mental notion of a "channel" or "connection" that potentially makes something available, then the choice of preposition is "to":

> It is [open/closed/available/perceptible] to visitors/humans.

In such cases (including yours), "for" is often possible, but it instead evokes the notion of "from the point of view of" or "for the benefit of". So both alternatives are grammatical, but evoke subtly different ideas. In this specific case, the likely idea that needs to be expressed is that of "simple availability", and probably for that reason, speakers would tend to opt for "to" in this case.

The choice of the second phrase probably comes down to a couple of factors:

- the use of the infinitive often suggests that the implied subject of the infinitive is the same as a previously expressed subject, whereas in this case, it would not be the public that was doing the cleaning (this isn't a hard and fast rule: it's perfectly possible to have the implied subject of an infinitive be different to one previously expressed, but this tends to happen where there is a very clear or "default" subject intended);
- the use of 'to' with the infinitive strongly suggests the initiation of an action; there is therefore a conflict if on the one hand you are expressing the non-availability but at the same time evoking the initiation of an activity involving the thing that is not available;
- there's nothing overt to make the word "cleaning and repair[ing]" sound overtly 'verb-like' rather than 'noun-like': no subject/object, no adverb.

Contrast your sentence with the following, where if you apply the factors above, the balance swings in favour of a verb:

> "The library is open to the public *to use* at their leisure"

Comment: Great explanation! :) 
The question is solved, i suppose.